# What is wrong with this version of foldr?

Tags: tex-core, loops

To gain a better understanding of macros, expansion and tex-core in general, I tried to implement `foldr` like this:

```
\long\def\cons#1#2{%
  \def\tmp{#2}%
  \ifx\tmp\nil%
    [#1,[]]%
  \else
    \consI{#1}#2%
  \fi
}%
\long\def\consI #1[#2]{%
  [#1,#2]%
}%
\def\nil{[]}%
\long\def\foldr(λ#1,#2->#3)#4[#5]{%
  \def\tempitem{#5}%
  \ifx\tempitem\nil%
    \def\next{#4}%
  \else
    \def\next{%
      \foldrI(λ#1,#2->#3)<#4>#5 %
    }%
  \fi
  \next
}%
\long\def\foldrI(λ#1,#2->#3)<#4>#5,#6{%
  \def#1{#5}%
  \def#2{\foldr(λ#1,#2->#3)#4[#6]}%
  #3 %
}%

\cons{4}{[3,[]]}\par
\foldr(λ\x,\acc->\cons\x\acc){\nil}[h,e,l,l,o,[]]\par
\end
```

`cons` seems to work fine;
However, `foldr` ends up with this error:

```
Runaway argument?
{\x }\acc \fi  ,l,o,, ]\par \end 
! File ended while scanning use of \consI.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

I am unsure where this is coming from; I am also unsure where the `\fi` is coming from in the error message.

To clear things up: i want empty lists to be `[[]]`, `[a,[]]` would be a one element list. The invocation of the `foldr` function at the end of the file should produce the exact same list that it was given as an argument.

I tried to keep the definition roughly similar to this implementation of an "element based loop"

```
\def\listingloopENDMARKER{\par \listingloopENDMARKER}
\long\def\listingloop#1in#2#3{%
  \looppicker{#1}{#3}#2,\listingloopENDMARKER,%
}%
\long\def\looppicker#1#2#3,{%
  \def\tempitem{#3}%
  \ifx\tempitem\listingloopENDMARKER
    \let\next=\relax%
  \else
    \def#1{#3}%
    #2%
    \def\next{\looppicker{#1}{#2}}%
  \fi
  \next
}%
\listingloop\x in{a,b,c,,d,e}{%
  The current item is ‘\x’
}
```

Maybe there is something wrong with the syntax I want the command to have?

Note that I am aware that this could probably more sensibly be done with latex3 and the sequence data structure; I am interested in solving it using tex only.

### EDIT

(code exaples given in haskell notation)

```haskell
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr f initial b = b
foldr f initial (a:t) = f a (foldr f initial t)
```

so it is a function that takes a function as an argument,
walks over the given list.
it basically provides the given function `f` with an element of the list and an accumulating value `acc` (starting out as `initial`).

examples:

```haskell
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3] == 0+3+2+1
foldr (\x acc -> cons x acc) [] [1,2,3] == [1,2,3]
foldr (\x acc -> cons (x+1) acc) [] [1,2,3] == map (+1) [1,2,3] == [2,3,4]
foldr (\x acc -> "_" ++ x ++ acc) "" ["hi","this","is"] == "_hi_this_is"
```

Comment: Your first `\ifx` compares `{` with the first token in `#2` (after argument replacement), so it will usually return false. It would help if you describe what `\foldr` is supposed to do. Another problem is that your macros don't work by pure expansion, so they won't behave in `\message`.

Comment: @egreg I updated the question with a description of foldr and changed the `\ifx` part to something (hopefully better); I am still unsure when `{}` groups characters to one single parameter and when they are just plain characters. (maybe I understood that wrong in  the first place)

Comment: You could look at the implementation of fold in plain tex  in lambda.sty https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/lambda-lists?lang=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in

```
\foldr(λ\x,\acc->\cons\x\acc){\nil}[h,e,l,l,o,[]]
```

`#5` is `h,e,l,l,o,[` (terminating at the first `]`)

You would need

```
 \foldr(λ\x,\acc->\cons\x\acc){\nil}[{h,e,l,l,o,[]}]
```

But as you will always need brace groups to guard nested `[]` it may be better to use a different syntax that uses `{..}` rather than `[...]` for list construction.